# Adding between dates - sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Currently  I have a query that will get me the data from the pervious month .

I need to change thisso I can choose a selected date range that could allow me to input 2 dates and pull back all results between them.

See my query below:

```
 select * from Table1 I
  inner join Service K on I.Service_Key = K.Service_Key
  inner join Status S on I.Status_Key = S.Status_Key
  where K.Service_Key = '1' 
 and S.Status_Name = 'Closed'
 and month(I.Date_Key) = (select case when Month (GETDATE())-1 = 0 then 12 else Month (GETDATE())-1 end)
 and year(I.Date_Key) =  (select case when Month (GETDATE()) -1 = 0 then year (GETDATE()) -1 ELSE YEAR (GETDATE()) end)
```

I need to be able to say where dates between dd/mm/yy and dd/mm/yy

Comment: Aside: Your date handling is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), i.e. it cannot benefit from index seeks on `Date_Key`. Computing starting and ending dates and using them, as in Foster90's and Dr. Linoff's answers, allows index seeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the dates a variables:

```
Declare @Startdate as datetime 
Declare @Enddate as datetime
set @Startdate = '01-AUG-20'
set @Enddate = '22-OCT-20'

select * from Table1 I
inner join Service K on I.Service_Key = K.Service_Key
inner join Status S on I.Status_Key = S.Status_Key
where K.Service_Key = '1' 
and S.Status_Name = 'Closed'
and I.Date_Key > @Startdate
and I.Date_Key < @Enddate
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is:

```
where K.Service_Key = '1' and
      S.Status_Name = 'Closed' and
      datediff(month, i.Date_key, getdate()) = 1
```

That version, however, cannot use an index on `i.Date_Key` if that is appropriate.  A more index friendly version is:

```
where K.Service_Key = '1' and
      S.Status_Name = 'Closed' and
      i.Date_key < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      i.Date_key >= dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```